# Increment count after rotation of a dial in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

So basically what I would like to do is take a Dial in Qt and display the number of times a user has rotated it using LCD Number. The signal would be when the slider is moved 360 degrees, increment the counter and display that number. If we define a threshold to pass, such as 359, then the user can abuse that by simply passing by the threshold numerous times. If we simply count how many degrees the dial has traveled, the user could abuse that as well by traveling back and forth without ever really traveling along the full length of the dial. So I suppose the method to get this to work properly is once they travel either 360 or -360 units in a direction, the count is incremented; if the user were to change their direction, their new distance would cancel out with their previous travel distance, allowing for a true rotation. This is the code I have thus far:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->connect(this->ui->dial, SIGNAL(sliderMoved(int)), this,SLOT(dial_incrementer()));
    this->counter = 0;
    this->ui->lcdNumber->display(counter);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::dial_incrementer()
{
    counter++;
    this->ui->lcdNumber->display(counter);
}
```

and my header:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    int counter;

private slots:
    void dial_incrementer();

    void on_dial_sliderMoved(int position);
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Unfortunately, I'm not exactly sure where to take it from here; sliderMoved() is of course operating so that whenever the dial moves a unit at all, the count is incrementing, which obviously isn't what we want.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental trick is to detect the rotation direction. In `dial_incrementer()` you need to subtract the new value and the (memorized) previous value. The sign of resulting number will give you the rotation direction.